# Will Apple accept if the app built with Base SDK iOS4.1 , not with iOS4.2?

Tags: ios, ios4, appstore-approval

I have installed the latest iOS4.2.1 for my app development recently. I have developed the Universal App built with Base SDK iOS4.2 and target SDK3.0.

When I test the app in iPad, there is no issue. But when I test the app in iPhone with iOS4.2.1, there is problem on typing in the Textfield, the app crashes. So, I built the app in XCode by setting Base SDK as OS4.1, this issue won't happen in the iPhone with iOS4.2.1. So I have planned to built the app with Base SDK 4.1.

As the latest version of iOS is 4.2.1, will Apple accept my app built with iOS4.1?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards, Mahesh.

Comment: you might want to make sure that your 4.1 version runs well on an iPad with 4.2 installed, though it sounds like you're saying you've already done that.

Comment: Why don't you fix the issue (or at least write a workaround) rather than just relying on an older SDK to build against? Apple won't wait for you while they move on, and you should always build against the latest SDK. If your app crashes when build against the latest SDK, then fix it because something is clearly wrong, don't just ignore it and carry on with the old SDK. If you can't fix it because of an SDK bug or something similar, work around it, and submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they accept apps built against the 4.x API, so you should be fine.

However, the real solution here is to fix the bug that causes the crash. Nothing has changed substantially with text field delegates since the first SDK (2.x) so it seems unlikely that a 0.1 update to the OS is the underlying cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but since there are tons of apps currently on the AppStore that weren't built against SDK 4.2, I'd be surprised if this was an issue.